# How to change the format of a float number?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I would change this:

```
0.18115942028986
```

to this

```
18.1159
```

How can i do with `number_format` or another function in php ?

Comment: 0.18115942028986 * 100 = 18.1159

Comment: Use [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) after multiplying by 100: `round(0.18115942028986 * 100, 4) = 18.1159`

Comment: thanks eveyone for helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myNewValue = floor($myValue*1000000)/10000;
```

more at [PHP FLOOR](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.floor.php) - [PHP CEIL](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ceil.php) - [PHP ROUND](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.round.php)